# How can I increase my Shopify websites load time?

Tags: shopify

Our clients website load really slow on the first load (the TTFB on the page document can be 10-20s). If I reload the page, the site loads a lot faster. 
This may be because of a lot of the files are cached?

Website is here: https://www.mortels.com.au/

This happens for a lot of the pages.

I have tried merging some of the .css files, and will try to attempt the .js files if I cannot find anything else (I never built the original theme, so finding it hard to figure out what is done where and do not have much experience with developing in Shopify.

I also tried adding a lazyloader however it doesn't look like it is working.

Would anyone have any solutions to make the website load quicker? Could it be just the apps we have running on the website causing the initial response to be so slow?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that can hinder your site's load speed is having too much logic happening through Liquid tags.  Shopify has  to parse all of the page's Liquid code before it can serve the page, and that has a direct effect on the TTFB

For the files that have unacceptable TTFB ratings, some things you can try to do to help make Shopify's servers serve your content faster include:

- Reducing the number of lookups (eg: through `all_products[handle]` on the page
- Avoiding nested `for` whenever possible
- Replacing loops with `map` whenever you need to make an array of values
- Rewriting logic-heavy sections to run in Javascript instead of Liquid (and using the `| json` filter to drop your liquid variables in a Javascript-friendly version)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am unsure of if there are any loops happening, on the homepage anyway. I will have to go through and check.